# Firefox 11+ Add-on SDK can you create a toolbar at the top of window below address bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, window, toolbar, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a toolbar for a customer, that wants a traditional IE style toolbar at the top of the window under the address bar.

This is what I have:
[What I have http://www.hellometro.com/toolbar/now.png](http://www.hellometro.com/toolbar/now.png)

Notice that because of vertical limitations of the status bar I have to write in all-caps for the letters to be legible while being small enough to fit. (two left most elements in status bar, text field and SEARCH button)

This is what I need:
[What I need http://www.hellometro.com/toolbar/whatiwant.png](http://www.hellometro.com/toolbar/whatiwant.png)

Notice the toolbar added to the top that has enough vertical space for legible text within text field and button. (Top left below browser's back button).

I'm looking for a way for positioning the search component at the status bar as a default location, and allow the user to change its position in the options page to let them pick top or bottom (because many if not most Firefox users don't know they can move Add-ons around).

My question is: Does Firefox Add-on SDK support what I want to do, or do I have to switch languages and approach solution from a different angle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't something that you can do with the available Add-on SDK API, with good reason - add-ons shouldn't waste screen estate unnecessarily and adding a toolbar is just that. You can achieve this goal by using low-level modules and going to the browser's XUL directly. Something like this should work (untested code and *very* hacky):

```js
var widgetID = "foobar";
var buttonID = "widget:" + require("self").id + "-" + widgetID;
var toolbarName = "My Extension Toolbar";
require("widget").Widget({
  id: widgetID,
  ...
});

if (firstRun)
{
  var winUtils = require("window-utils");
  for (var window in winUtils.browserWindowIterator())
  {
    var toolbox = window.gNavToolbox;
    if (toolbox)
    {
      // Does the button exist already?
      var button = toolbox.ownerDocument.getElementById(buttonID);
      if (button && button.parentNode.getAttribute("toolbarname") == toolbarName)
        continue;  // Button already in the right toolbar
      else if (button)
      {
        // Remove button from its current location
        var toolbar = button.parentNode;
        toolbar.removeChild(button);

        // Make sure this change is persisted
        toolbar.setAttribute("currentset", toolbar.currentSet);
        toolbar.ownerDocument.persist(toolbar.id, "currentset");
      }

      var toolbar = toolbox.appendCustomToolbar("My Extension Toolbar", buttonID);
      toolbar.currentSet = toolbar.getAttribute("currentset");
      toolbar.ownerDocument.persist(toolbar.id, "currentset");

      // Send change notification, the widget needs reinitializing
      var event = toolbox.ownerDocument.createEvent("Events");
      event.initEvent("customizationchange", true, true);
      toolbox.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Note the undefined `firstRun` variable - you want to do this only once, otherwise you will revert user's choice to move your widget elsewhere (you can store a flag via `simple-prefs` module or something like that). Also note that `buttonID` calculation uses internal details from the `addon-kit/lib/widget.js` file in the SDK - the way the toolbar button ID is calculated can change in a future SDK version but I think that this is the only way to get hold of a widget you create with the SDK. There are plenty of internals in the other parts of the code as well of course.

Documentation: [`window-utils` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/packages/api-utils/window-utils.html) (`browserWindowIterator` is undocumented), [`<xul:toolbox>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/toolbox), [`<xul:toolbar>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/toolbar).

Comment: While trying to use your suggestion, I accidentally created two toolbars with the same name.  Now Toolbar Layout... is grayed out.  Where can I go to delete my two custom toolbars with the same name?

Comment: Nevermind about the delete duplicates.  I closed Firefox and opened it again, which consolidated the two toolbars with the same name (or at least deleted the second).

Comment: Ok, I put this into my code, but it only succeeds in creating the custom toolbar and removing the widget from the Add-on Toolbar.  The widget never appears on the new custom toolbar.

Comment: Ok, I edited you code example, so now it does move the widget to the new custom toolbar, but it does not stay there, if I restart Firefox, the widget goes back to the Add-on Toolbar.

Comment: @RobertLouisMurphy: I added two code lines that should make sure that the button is actually added and persisted.

Comment: Removing my newToolbar code and adding your new three lines did not appear to help.

Answer (score 2):

As of Firefox 29 ( as of this writing in Beta ) you can very easily add toolbar buttons to Firefox, please see this blog post on how to do it using the Add-on SDK:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/13/new-add-on-sdk-australis-ui-features-in-firefox-29/

You can also do this via lower-level apis, see this hacks post for more information:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/06/australis-for-add-on-developers-2/